# Как убрать кулдаун команды для определенной роли/администратора в Discord?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Вот код:

```
@client.command(aliases=['идея', 'ИДЕЯ', 'IDEA'])
@commands.cooldown(1, 60, commands.BucketType.user)
async def idea(ctx,*, idea=None):
  if ctx.author.id == 958724597153402892:
    
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send("ваша идея отправлена разработчикам")
    await client.get_channel(settings['ADMINCHAT']).send(f"<@&{(settings['DEVELOPERROLE'])}> Идея от {ctx.author}: \"{(idea)}\"")
    print(f'{ctx.author} || {ctx.author.id} отправил идею: \"{(idea)}\"')
```

Как сделать что бы для определенной роли не было кулдауна на эту команду?

Comment: Медленный режим для канала включен?

Comment: медленный режим отключен

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command(aliases=['идея', 'ИДЕЯ', 'IDEA'])
@commands.cooldown(1, 60, commands.BucketType.user)
async def idea(ctx,*, idea=None):
    if ctx.author.id == 958724597153402892:
        role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'название_роли', ctx.message.server.roles)
        if role in ctx.message.author.roles:
            idea.reset_cooldown(ctx)
    
            await ctx.message.delete()
            await ctx.send("ваша идея отправлена разработчикам")
            await client.get_channel(settings['ADMINCHAT']).send(f"<@&{(settings['DEVELOPERROLE'])}> Идея от {ctx.author}: \"{(idea)}\"")
            print(f'{ctx.author} || {ctx.author.id} отправил идею: \"{(idea)}\"')
        else:
            await ctx.message.delete()
            await ctx.send("ваша идея отправлена разработчикам")
            await client.get_channel(settings['ADMINCHAT']).send(f"<@&{(settings['DEVELOPERROLE'])}> Идея от {ctx.author}: \"{(idea)}\"")
            print(f'{ctx.author} || {ctx.author.id} отправил идею: \"{(idea)}\"')
```